# No "available widgets" (wordpress 3.2.1 multisite)

Tags: themes, widgets

I have no widgets available any ideas?

I've tried the "Twenty Eleven" Standard Theme and the custom one (Lotus).

No widgets are listed, I am looking for the custom_menu widget.

In my other wordpress installation I have plenty of widgets available.

**Update**: I use a multisite installation and I found that the blog_id in wp_options is set to 0 (not sure this has something to do with it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, I commented this out by mistake in wp-includes/widgets.php line 323:

```
function register($widget_class) {
//      $this->widgets[$widget_class] = & new $widget_class();
}
```